# Two-dimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, array, matrix

I have a bit of trouble with two-dimensional arrays in C. I want to pass such an array to a function accepting a pointer to pointers. I figured no way of really passing the array itself. Furthermore, I am not very sure if my solution is perfect practice because it is very circuitous and long. Especially because this should be a library documentation, I want to have the best way of doing it possible. To the code:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_STRING 256
#define ALPHABET_LENGTH 26
#define MAX_ASCII 128
#define MAX_TEMP 256

void lsoeSolveRecursive(double**, double[], int, int);
void lsoePartition(double**, int);
void lsoeElimination(double**, int, int);
void lsoeSwap(double**, int, int);
void lsoeExpand(double**, int);
void lsoeShrink(double**, int);

int getDecimalPlaces(double);
int lcm(int, int);
int gcd(int, int);

void seSearch(char[], char[], char[], int, int, double**);
bool seIsDigit(char);

const char possibleVarNames[] = "xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int power;

void lsoeSolve(double **matrix, double matrixr[], int matrixc)
{
    lsoePartition(matrix, matrixc);
    lsoeSolveRecursive(matrix, matrixr, matrixc, 1);
}

void lsoeSolveRecursive(double **matrix, double matrixr[], int matrixc, int i)
{
    double res = matrix[matrixc - i][matrixc];

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        res -= matrixr[matrixc - j] * matrix[matrixc - i][matrixc - j];

    matrixr[matrixc - i] = res / matrix[matrixc - i][matrixc - i];

    if (i != matrixc)
        lsoeSolveRecursive(matrix, matrixr, matrixc, i + 1);
}

void lsoePartition(double **matrix, int matrixc)
{
    double part[2][matrixc + 1];

    for (int a1 = 0; a1 < matrixc - 1; a1++)
        for (int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < matrixc; a2++)
        {
            for (int j = a1; j < matrixc + 1; j++)
            {
                part[0][j] = matrix[a1][j];
                part[1][j] = matrix[a2][j];
            }


            if (part[0][a1] == 0 || part[1][a1] == 0)
            {
                if (part[0][a1] == 0)
                    lsoeSwap(matrix, a1, a2);
                break;
            }

            double *arg[2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                arg[i] = part[i];

            lsoeElimination(arg, matrixc, a1);

            for (int j = a1; j < matrixc + 1; j++)
            {
                matrix[a1][j] = part[0][j];
                matrix[a2][j] = part[1][j];
            }
        }
}

void lsoeElimination(double **part, int matrixc, int index)
{
    lsoeExpand(part, matrixc);

    int leastCommonMultiply = abs(lcm(part[0][index], part[1][index]));
    double factor = leastCommonMultiply / fabs(part[0][index]);

    if (part[0][index] > 0)
        for (int i = index; i < matrixc + 1; i++)
            part[0][i] *= -(factor);
    else
        for (int i = index; i < matrixc + 1; i++)
            part[0][i] *= factor;

    factor = leastCommonMultiply / fabs(part[1][index]);

    if (part[1][index] < 0)
        for (int i = index; i < matrixc + 1; i++)
            part[1][i] *= -(factor);
    else
        for (int i = index; i < matrixc + 1; i++)
            part[1][i] *= factor;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixc + 1; i++)
        part[1][i] += part[0][i];

    lsoeShrink(part, matrixc);
}

void lsoeSwap(double **array, int a, int b)
{
    double *temp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = temp;
}

void lsoeExpand(double **part, int matrixc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixc + 1; j++)
        {
            int decimalPlaces;
            decimalPlaces = getDecimalPlaces(part[i][j]);
            if (decimalPlaces > power)
                power = decimalPlaces;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixc + 1; j++)
            part[i][j] = part[i][j] * pow(10, power);
}

void lsoeShrink(double **part, int matrixc)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixc + 1; j++)
            part[i][j] = part[i][j] * pow(10, -power);
}

int getDecimalPlaces(double n)
{
    char string[MAX_STRING];
    int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 0;
    int i = sprintf(string, "%f", n);
    bool countZero = false;
    for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        if (string[j] == '.')
            break;
        if (!countZero && string[j] != 48)
            countZero = true;
        if (countZero)
            numberOfDecimalPlaces++;
    }
    return numberOfDecimalPlaces;
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b % a, a);
}

int lcm(int a, int b)
{
    return a / gcd(a, b) * b;
}

void seEvaluate(char **line, int linec, double **matrix) // linec: Anzahl Zeilen
{
    bool ascii[MAX_ASCII], v[ALPHABET_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ASCII; i++)
    {
        ascii[i] = false;
        v[i % ALPHABET_LENGTH] = false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < linec; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(line[i]); j++)
            ascii[(int) line[i][j]] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        if (i < 23)
        {
            if (ascii[i + 97])
                v[i + 3] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ascii[i + 97])
                v[i - 23] = true;
        }
    }

    char vars[ALPHABET_LENGTH] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_LENGTH; i++)
        if (v[i])
        {
            char str[2] = "\0";
            str[0] = possibleVarNames[i];
            strcat(vars, str);
        }

3 
    char temp[MAX_TEMP];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(vars); i++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TEMP; i++)
            temp[i] = 0;
        seSearch(line[i], vars, temp, 0, i, matrix);
    }
}

void seSearch(char equation[], char vars[], char temp[], int index, int row,
        double **matrix)
{
    if (seIsDigit(equation[index]) || equation[index] == '-')
    {
        char str[2] = "\0";
        str[0] = equation[index];
        strcat(temp, str);
    }

    else if (equation[index] == '.' || equation[index] == ',')
        strcat(temp, ".");
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(vars); i++)
        {
            if (equation[index] == vars[i])
            {
                if (strcmp(temp, "") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "\0") == 0
                        || strcmp(temp, "-") == 0)
                    strcat(temp, "1");
                matrix[row][i] = strtod(temp, NULL);
                memset(temp, 0, MAX_TEMP);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (index + 1 < strlen(equation))
        seSearch(equation, vars, temp, index + 1, row, matrix);
    else
        matrix[row][strlen(vars)] = strtod(temp, NULL);
}
bool seIsDigit(char c)
{
    if (c > 47 && c < 58)
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Number of results equal to the rows of the linear system of equations.
#define NUMBER_OF_RESULTS 4

int main(void)
{
    // Example matrix entered as 4 strings.
    char stringMatrix[NUMBER_OF_RESULTS][256] =
    { "3x + 4y -5z + 6a = 39", 
    "6x + 5y - 6z + 5a = 43",
    "9x - 4y + 2z + 3a = 6", 
    "2y - 3z + a = 13" };

    // Array for storing the results.
    double matrixr[NUMBER_OF_RESULTS];

    // Turning the matrix to pointer array suitable for functions.
    char *pMatrix[NUMBER_OF_RESULTS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RESULTS; i++)
        pMatrix[i] = stringMatrix[i];

    // Array for storing the result of string evaluation.
    static double resMatrix[NUMBER_OF_RESULTS][NUMBER_OF_RESULTS+1];

    // Turning the coefficient matrix suitable for functions.
    double *pRetMatrix[NUMBER_OF_RESULTS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RESULTS; i++)
        pRetMatrix[i] = resMatrix[i];

    // Evaluating the string matrix.
    seEvaluate(pMatrix, NUMBER_OF_RESULTS, pRetMatrix);
    // Solving the coefficient matrix.
    lsoeSolve(pRetMatrix, matrixr, NUMBER_OF_RESULTS);

    // Printing out the results.
    printf("Linear System Of Equations:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%s\n", stringMatrix[i]);
    printf("--> ");
    printf("x = %.2f, y = %.2f, z = %.2f, a = %.2f", matrixr[0], matrixr[1],
        matrixr[2], matrixr[3]);
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you know a better way for doing so, I would be very pleased with an answer. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I want to use two-dimensional **arrays** in functions furthermore, but can't find a way of doing without converting them to **pointers** the messy way described.

Edit 2: I appended the full source code as a working one working file now. I hope it helps you.

Edit 3: The concrete purpose is transfering a string array to a matrix of coefficients and the solving it as a linear system of equations.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: `seEvaluate` and `lsoeSolve` are missing, so this does not compile. Perhaps a stub would be appropriate? As it stands, you are not producing any output. Maybe a simple testing function would be good to demonstrate/test?

Comment: `know a better way for doing so` There may be *ways to achieve same* better in some intuitive way. For *doing **so***, I lack an intuition for *good/better*. [stack**overflow** is a better fit for "how-to" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24623778).

Comment: You seem to be looking for feedback on the way the processing (give it a name: declare a function) is coded. While this was squarely on-topic, your question should not be answered in its 1st revision: The part presented collapses using the appropriate mechanism, `seEvaluate()` and `lsoeSolve()` are missing. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question states "The function handling the arrays is complicated, so I left it out.", but that's no longer true after your latest edit I think.

Comment: Luqus, Do you really want `double part[2][matrixc + 1];`  and use in `int` functions like `abs(part[0][index])`?

Comment: I find it hard to follow what you are doing. You may want to clearly separate the parsing and the solving. Having an object `struct input` that has the strings and `struct lsoe` that has all of the matrix and the dimensions that you extracted would probably help.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, I changed `abs()` to `fabs()` in these cases now.